# UIViewController and tableView below status Bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewcontroller that has a tableView. I want view and tableView to start from the top point of status bar (under status bar). How can I achieve that?

**See the image , i want image to come under status bar**

[image: See the image , i want image to come under status bar[1]]

Comment: Please show us the screenshot, what u achieved.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, its confusing

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can hide status bar with this code in your view controller

   ```
   override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
      return true
   }
   ```
2. If you don't want to hide status bar you can set your table view's top constraint equal to super view's top

[image]

This worked for me

[image]

Orange view is under status bar

Comment: No i want to to come under status bar. I have set it 0 but still table content are starting after status bar. I want content to overlap with status bar.

Answer (score 3):

You should set your UITableView's top constraint equal to the top of the super view, not safe area.

To do this you can move your UITableView a little out of the screen view (from top) and then set the top constraint to 0.